# ENOENT while trying to read a zipped file

Tags: ruby, rubyzip

I'm writing a simple program that takes an input string, splits it in words and saves it in it's memory. There's three methods -- to save a string into memory, to load from file and to load from zip archive. Here's the code:

```
require 'zip'

class Storage
  def initialize
    @storage = ''
  end

  def add(string)
    words = string.split ','
    words.each do |word|
      @storage << "#{word},"
    end
  end

  def load_from_file(filename)
    File.open filename, 'r' do |f|
      f.each { |line| add line }
    end
  end

  def load_from_zip(filename)
    Zip::File.open "#{filename}.zip" do |zipfile|
      zipfile.each { |entry| load_from_file entry.to_s }
    end
  end
end
```

While `add` and `load_from_file` methods work perfectly as I expect, `load_from_zip` returns me the following error each time I try to run it:

```
storage.rb:39:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - test.txt (Errno::ENOENT)
```

Although the file exists in my archive. I would appreciate any suggestion on what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Zip::File.open "#{filename}.zip"
```

does not extract the zip file, it just opens it and shows what's inside.
You cannot call

```
File.open filename, 'r'
```

since `filename` isn't in your filesystem, just inside the .zip file.

You'll need to add a new method :

```
require 'zip'

class Storage
  def initialize
    @storage = ''
  end

  def add(string)
    words = string.split ','
    words.each do |word|
      @storage << "#{word},"
    end
  end

  def load_from_file(filename)
    File.open filename, 'r' do |f|
      f.each { |line| add line }
    end
  end

  def load_from_zip(filename)
    Zip::File.open "#{filename}.zip" do |zipfile|
      zipfile.each { |entry| load_from_zipped_file(zipfile,entry)}
    end
  end

  private

  def load_from_zipped_file(zipfile, entry)
    zipfile.read(entry).lines.each do |line|
      add line
    end
  end
end

s = Storage.new
s.load_from_zip('test')
```